# The API is throwing wrong response code 500 internal error instead 204

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

We observed a sudden change in the behavior of API response codes.
In my local system it's retuning **204 - No Content fine**. But, after deploying into **Azure App Service** (running ASP.NET 4.8 stack), it's returning **500 internal error** ( requested from Post man tool as shown in the attached pictures)

**Please Note:** It was working earlier with the same code and in the App Service

We can reproduce the issue with simple code below in Web API (4.6.1 FW I am using)

Suspecting its due to some Pass level changes. **Please share if any one facing similar issue or any clues how to fix this issue.**

Its simple to reproduce the issue  with below line of code Web API and triggering the request Local vs App Service (will be greatfull if any one can re-produce to understand the real issue I am trying to convey. Thanks.

**Code Snippet**
[image]

**Local : no Issue**
[image]

**Issue after deploying into App Service**
[image]

Comment: If the App Service is configured to run on .NET Framework 4.8 and your application is compiled as 4.6.1, have you tried migrating your application to 4.8 and redeploying? Although official documentation states that should not be necessary, I would at least try it to eliminate the possibility that that's the issue. Are you using anu old packages that might rely on older version of .NET?

Comment: For reference: [Runtime Changes for Migration from .NET Framework 4.6.1 to 4.8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/runtime/4.6.1-4.8)

Comment: A 500 indicates the service crashed.  You need to determine where the service crashed.  Turning on diagnostic logging to review the stack trace that is caused and/or doing remote debugging during the call that returns a 500 is the appropriate next step.

Comment: Hi Rickvdbosch  , @RithwikBojja-MT, It looks to be configuration or coding but as I said, it working earlier with same configuration in App service with the same code.  I will be great full if you can try in your system with small piece of code I shared locally vs in deployed in app service, you really understand the real issue I would to Convery the problem.

Comment: You should not return a body in your response with a 204 status code.  

From W3C: The 204 response MUST NOT include a message-body.  

Sources:  
[W3C](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)  
[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Root of this issue:** After lot of analysis and discussions with Microsoft Teams, understood that there is recent introduction of higher security compliance in front of Azure Front End. This change enforcing that **content should not be returned with HTTP 204.** ( Reference source: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html )

**Why it was working earlier:** Because It was compatible and no issues even we return Content in the 204 response before.

**Mitigation**

- Approach 1:
  Avoid returning content with 204 response.
- Approach 2:
  Disable security compliance as Quick fix and slowly update your code not to return content with 204 response.